# Spring Boot with Security OAuth2 - how to use resource server with web login form?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have **Spring Boot** (1.2.1.RELEASE) application that serves **OAuth2** (2.0.6.RELEASE) authorization and resource server in one application instance. It uses custom `UserDetailsService` implementation that makes use of `MongoTemplate` to search users in MongoDB. Authentication with `grant_type=password` on `/oauth/token` works like a charm, as well as authorization with `Authorization: Bearer {token}` header while calling for specific resources.

Now I want to add simple OAuth confirm dialog to the server, so I can authenticate and authorize e.g. Swagger UI calls in api-docs for protected resources. Here is what I did so far:

```
@Configuration
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
class OAuth2ServerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService

        @Autowired
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder

        ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher


        @Bean
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider()
            provider.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder
            provider.userDetailsService = userDetailsService
            return provider
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        }

        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            //return super.authenticationManagerBean()
            ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager([daoAuthenticationProvider()], super.authenticationManagerBean())
            providerManager.setAuthenticationEventPublisher(new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher))
            return providerManager
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            new BCryptPasswordEncoder(5)
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value('${oauth.resourceId}')
        private String resourceId

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier('authenticationManagerBean')
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.setSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class, authenticationManager)

            http.csrf().disable()
            http.httpBasic().disable()

            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()

            //http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())

            http.anonymous().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers('/login/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/register/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/activate/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/password/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/account/**').hasAuthority('ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/api-docs/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/admin/**').hasAuthority('SUPERADMIN')
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

            //http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(resourceId)
            resources.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value('${oauth.clientId}')
        private String clientId

        @Value('${oauth.secret:}')
        private String secret

        @Value('${oauth.resourceId}')
        private String resourceId

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier('authenticationManagerBean')
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
            return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()")
            oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient(clientId)
                    .secret(secret)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds(resourceId)
        }
    }
}
```

Main problem is that I cannot make both (web login form and OAuth2 authorization token in header) running. If `ResourceServer` gets higher priority, then OAuth2 token authorization works, but I can't login using web form. On the other hand if I set the higher priority to `LoginConfig` class, then OAuth2 token authorization stops working.

#### Case study: Login form works, OAuth2 token authorization does not

I figured out that in that case the problem is caused by non-registered `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. I tried to registered it manually in `ResourceServer.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method, but it didn't work - I could see the filter on FilterChain list, but it didn't get triggered. It wasn't good way to fix it, because there is a lot of other magic done during the ResourceServer initialization so I moved to the second case.

#### Case study: Login form does not work, OAuth2 token authorization works

In that case the main problem is that by default `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` cannot find a properly configured `AuthenticationProvider` instance (in `ProviderManager`). When I tried to add it manually by:

```
http.authenticationProvide(daoAuthenticationProvider())
```

it gets one, but in this case there is no `AuthenticationEventPublisher` defined and successful authentication cannot be published to other components. And in fact in the next iteration it gets replaced by `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`. That's why I tried to define manually `AuthenticationManager` instance with `DaoAuthenticationProvider` inside:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    //return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager([daoAuthenticationProvider()], super.authenticationManagerBean())
    providerManager.setAuthenticationEventPublisher(new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher))
    return providerManager
}
```

I thought it will work, but there is a different problem with providing `AuthenticationManager` instance to registered filters. It turns out that each filter has `authenticationManager` injected manually using `sharedObjects` component:

```
authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class));
```

The problem here is that you are not guaranteed to have a proper instance set, because there is a simple HashMap ([check it on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/9654817fd85c5081c3874060ea30b9bec9a7934e/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java#L252)) used to store specific shared object and it can be change any time. I tried to set it in:

```
http.setSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class, authenticationManager)
```

but before I get to the place where it is being read, it's already replaced by default implementation. I checked it with the debugger and it looks like that for each new filter there is a new instance of authentication manager.

**My question is:** am I doing it correctly? How can I set up authorization server with the resources server integrated in one application with login form (OAuth2 dialog) working? Maybe it can be done in a different and much easier way. I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution to the problem. Take a look at this exemplary `Groovy` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value('${oauth.resourceId}')
    private String resourceId

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        http.httpBasic().disable()

        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers('/admin/**', '/uaa/**')
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/authenticated/**').authenticated()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/register/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/activate/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/password/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/auth/**').permitAll()
                    .antMatchers('/uaa/account/**').hasAuthority('ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/admin/**').hasAuthority('ADMIN')
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceId);
    }
}
```

Basically, to run OAuth2.0 authentication parallel with web form authentication, you have to put

```
http.requestMatchers().antMatchers('/path/1/**', '/path/2/**')
```

to configuration class. My previous configuration missed this important part so only OAuth2.0 took a part in authentication process.

Comment: Hi, but basic auth is not disabled. Popup is coming everytime! What should be done? Please help

Comment: Hello Stephniak, In the case of the LoginForm security configuration, did you reuse the one from the original post? I'm also interested in combining OAuth with other type of authentication/authorization, in my case, SpringSession clustering. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you should be trying to set up form login or http basic in your `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, and certainly not if you already have them in your other `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (you do because they are on by default). It might work, but the authentication and access decisions are so different for an OAuth2 protected resource and a UI that I recommend you keep them separate (as they are in all the samples in github). If you go with the recommendation and continue with the components you already defined, the key to getting this right is to know that the filter chains are tried sequentially and the first one to match wins, so only one of them is going to act on any given request. You have to put request matchers in both chains (or at least the one with the lowest order), and make sure they don't overlap.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for coming with an idea. I already found what was wrong with my resource server configuration, I will post it here shortly. Now the form based login and oauth token authentication works just fine.

Comment: hi @SzymonStepniak. Would you please share your solution.

Comment: Hey @Maksim, please find an answer below. Sorry you have to wait for it, I'm in the middle of analogue holiday season :)

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Can you please provide your solution? I would also like to replace the Basic Auth popup of the ResourceServer by a login form.

Answer (score 2):

what if you use different endpoints configured with different security?

For the above example, everything with /uaa/** secured with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and /api-docs/** with ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.

In that case, will filter chains still conflict?